# If norm of a sequence of vectors diverges, does inner product too?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

Let's say we're in a Hilbert Space $H$, and have a sequence of vectors $||v_{n}||$ in $H$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||v_{n}|| = \infty$. Fix $y \in H$. Is it true that in this case $\lim_{n \to \infty} (v_{n} \cdot y) = \infty$ as well?

My approach at prove this was looking at this as $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||v_{n}|| (\frac{v_{n}}{||v_{n}||} \cdot y)$, and noting that the $||v_{n}||$ on the outside would diverge. But the problem here is that the vector $\frac{v_{n}}{||v_{n}||}$ inside is changing as $n$ increases, meaning that a priori we have no way of knowing that $(\frac{v_{n}}{||v_{n}||} \cdot y)$ doesn't become arbitrarily small as $n$ increases, and thus we don't have divergence.

Comment: Even on the real line this is not true since the limit of the inner product can be $-\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

If $(e_n)$ is orthonormal then $\|ne_n\|=n \to \infty$ but $\langle ne_n , e_1 \rangle  \to 0$.

Comment: (+1) That's even simpler than what I was about to post.

Comment: In fact, $ne_2$ would work in two dimensions

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you. That is a good observation. Strictly speaking the result is false even in $\mathbb R$.